# The best overloaded method match for 'DBFunctions.getRunNo(int, ref string, ref int, int)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, .net

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The first method, I define some parameters ByRef in a class DBFunctions

```
 public string getRunNo(int REQ_ID, ref string file_name, ref int run_no, int MEMBER_ID)
        {
            string vError = String.Empty;
            Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter[] parameters;
            parameters = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter[6];
            for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
            {
                parameters[i] = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter();
            }
            parameters[0].ParameterName = "vREQ_ID";
            parameters[0].Value = REQ_ID;
            parameters[0].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

            parameters[1].ParameterName = "vMEMBER_ID";
            parameters[1].Value = MEMBER_ID;
            parameters[1].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

            parameters[2].ParameterName = "vFILE_TYPE";
            parameters[2].Value = "ENQUIRY";
            parameters[2].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

            parameters[3].ParameterName = "vSUB_FILE_TYPE";
            parameters[3].Value = "E";
            parameters[3].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

            parameters[4].ParameterName = "vFILE_NAME";
            parameters[4].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            parameters[5].ParameterName = "vRUN_NO";
            parameters[5].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            parameters[6].ParameterName = "vERR";
            parameters[6].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            string V_Error;
            OracleCommand MyCom = new OracleCommand("P_GENERATE_SIMAH_FILE_NAME", conn);

            MyCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            foreach (OracleParameter p in parameters)
            {
                MyCom.Parameters.Add(p);
            }

            try
            {
                MyCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                V_Error = ex.Message;
                return V_Error;
            }
            V_Error = MyCom.Parameters["vERR"].Value.ToString();
            if (V_Error == "-")
            {

            }

            return V_Error;
        }
```

Here, in the second class, I am instantiating it and calling the function

```
res = df.getRunNo(REQ_ID, file_name, RUN_NO, head.MEMBER_ID);
```

but I am getting the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'DBFunctions.getRunNo(int, ref
>   string, ref int, int)' has some invalid arguments

Can you please identify why is the error. If I remove the "ref", it works fine but I need reference variables.

Thanks,
Noorul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `ref` or `out` parameters, you need to add `ref` or `out` to the arguments when you call the method:

```
res = df.getRunNo(REQ_ID, ref file_name, ref RUN_NO, head.MEMBER_ID);
```

Having said that, I can't see where you're assigning to `file_name` or `run_no` in `getRunNo` so it doesn't look like those parameters need to be `ref` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, I missed assigning the values back to the referenced parameters.